# mouseover and mouseleave ON / OFF Not Working

Tags: jquery

here is my code in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4yb42/10/

the problem is after off `mouseover`or `mouseleave` by this code:

`jQuery('.star-rating span').off('mouseover mouseleave');`

how to ON or start again effect of `mouseover`or `mouseleave` ??

it is not working after you click fist time on `ClickMe1 ClickMe2 ClickMe3 ClickMe4 ClickMe4` (the convert in to red color) then click on reset button , and now mouse over on `ClickMe1 ClickMe2 ClickMe3 ClickMe4 ClickMe4` its on effect on mouse over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yb42/13/)***</kbd>

1. Defining function's for each event,
2. unbinding them using `of()` and
3. again binding those functions using `on()`.

*Code*

```
jQuery('.star-rating span').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        me(this);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        ml(this);
    },
    click: function () {
        cl(this);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Redeclare your mouseover and mouseleave event handlers
2. Instead of doing off, test a condition in your handlers