# toggle from event listening on a DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am seeking for a simple function to be called (without any arguments) over DOM element

1. That will stop listening to all the events binded to that DOM element and also on all of its children and grand children.
2. That will bring back that DOM element to listen back to all the events that was registed before calling function 1. Means getting back that DOM element to previous initial state.

How can i do that.

I have searched over www. I found that very relevent http://www.elijahmanor.com/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/ But could not found my answer

Just trying off() : It removed all the event handlers.
So calling back on() doesn't brings DOM element back to previous state.

So how can i achieve my goal?

Comment: Not a downvoter but what is the DOM structure you have and what exact code is not working for you would help in diagnosing the problem. Having an example on JSfidde would help as well.

Comment: Have you gone through jQuery off() documentation? I have seen a pretty good explanation for on() and off() actions. api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7ELwt/

Comment: once you click off... you never can on div again (div will stop listening forever)

Comment: yeah i have read the jquery docs.. call off() is off then how can i rebind all the events in one call without any arguments. Say i do not remember how many and what events i had binded to that DOM element. In that situation how can i get back all the binded events

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ELwt/1/)

Comment: @Rohith you are also rebinding the events again. what would i do it i don't remember what events i had had binded in past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access to the internal events list of each element, save the list somewhere such as as a property of the element (to restore later) and set the events list to `null` to remove all the events handlers. Here is the demo code:

**HTML**:

```
<div id='container'>
  <h2>Click me</h2>
  <div>
    Hover me
  </div>    
</div>
<label><input type='checkbox'/>Remove events</label>
```

**CSS**:

```
#container {
  padding:30px;
  background:red;
  width:200px;    
}
h2 {
  cursor:pointer;
}
#container > div {
  background:green;
  padding:30px;
}
```

**JS**:

```
//init events handlers
$('h2').click(function(e){
  alert('clgt?');
});
$('#container > div').hover(function(e){
    this.style.background = 'blue';
  }, function(e){
    this.style.background = 'green';
});

$('#container').hover(function(e){
    this.style.background = 'orange';
  }, function(e){
    this.style.background = 'red';
});

var elements = $('#container, #container *');

elements.each(function(i, e){
    //access to the events list of each element and save that list
    //into a property called events
    e.events = $._data(e, "events");      
});

$('input:checkbox').change(function(e){    
  if(this.checked) elements.each(function(i,elem){
    //off
    $._data(elem, "events", null);
  }) 
  else elements.each(function(i,elem){
    //on
    $._data(elem, "events", elem.events);
  })
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/2b7VZ/3/)

Note that the code above works when all the event handlers are registered once time **intially**, if then there may be others added, you should save the list into `events` property before setting it to `null` like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(e){    
  if(this.checked) elements.each(function(i,elem){
    //save first to restore later
    elem.events = $._data(elem, "events");
    //off
    $._data(elem, "events", null);
  }) 
  else elements.each(function(i,elem){
    //on
    $._data(elem, "events", elem.events);
  })
});
```

Comment: Your answer was very much correct to my needs. but i still think, this type of functionality (putting a blocking wall on DOM element, that will filter the event listeners to it and its all its children) should be given in JQuery by default.

Comment: @Koka if you want to filter even more deeply by event name, such as `click`, then you can just get all the `click` event handlers by `$._data(elem, "events")["click"]`. Here is the demo turning on/off only click handlers http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/2b7VZ/4/ . You can based on that to complete your code.

Answer (score 0):

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xJpNa/)

After using `off()` you need to bind all events again, something like this

```
$('#yes').click(function () {
    $('.parent, .children,.grandchildren').on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        },
        click: function () {
            alert(this.innerHTML);
        }
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle asked in the question](http://jsfiddle.net/7ELwt/2/)

[`Based on my answer here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23889422/2260614)

Comment: this is what i dont want to rebind all the events again.

Comment: in the edited fiddle rebinding is used again... i am not looking to rebind but just toggleing from listening state to not-listening state and vice-verce

Comment: @Koka you need to [read this](http://api.jquery.com/on/)... You always need to rebind it after using `off()`..